# Sampling based on polygon size/area

Tags: r, raster, r-sf, terra

I am trying to sample about 10000 points in multipolygon (12) with different sizes. The multipolygon has "ID" and "Area". I want the sample to be drawn based on each polygon size (area), i.e. more samples from larger polygons and less samples from smaller polygons of course based on their sizes. I tried the following

```
pol_sample = st_read("./Data/Polygons/Polygons_merged.shp")
pol_sample = st_transform(pol_sample, 4326)
pol_sample = st_sample(pol_sample, 10000)
```

But this will only sample randomly and will not consider the polygon sizes.

Could anyone help how to sample points based on polygon sizes?

Thank you a lot for your help.

Print out of sf object below:

```
Simple feature collection with 12 features and 2 fields
Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
Dimension:     XY
Bounding box:  xmin: -121.1789 ymin: -38.13566 xmax: 153.2769 ymax: 
42.17854
Geodetic CRS:  GCS_unknown
First 10 features:
ID  area_sqkm                       geometry
1 2380240.67 MULTIPOLYGON (((77.46847 11...
2 1609475.32 MULTIPOLYGON (((148.3452 -2...
3  609946.15 MULTIPOLYGON (((118.0327 27...
4  895408.10 MULTIPOLYGON (((36.70649 -1...
5  999426.57 MULTIPOLYGON (((35.4854 -1....
6 4961657.01 MULTIPOLYGON (((-64.37801 -...
7 4930984.79 MULTIPOLYGON (((-93.46362 1...
8 1010392.03 MULTIPOLYGON (((-68.31586 1...
9   79048.80 MULTIPOLYGON (((-80.51816 2...
10   47379.37 MULTIPOLYGON (((-69.62635 1..."
```

Comment: Does the `st_sample` function have a probability argument? If so, pass on the probability that is proporcional to size

Comment: Could you share a printout of your sf object or better yet, include a reproducible example? Reprex could be based on simple geometries or perhaps on `st_read(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf"))` . From the question it's not quite clear if you have a single multipolygon (1 row in sf object, an union of 12 geometries), or 12 multipolygons (12 rows in sf object). For the latter, do you want to use existing `Area` col? `st_sample` returns only a geometry list, how did match those points to your polygons? Or if you didn't, how do you know the distribution isn't proportional to polygon areas?

Comment: I merged 12 separate polygons into one. After getting the points, I was visualizing in arcgis to confirm.

Comment: I have added the sf object print out. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can't quite agree with the claim that `st_sample()` will not consider the polygon sizes when called with `st_sample(x, 10000)`. You'll not get the same proportions as for areas, but you should still get reasonably high p-values (i.e nowhere near 0.05) when you compare resulting sample point ID counts against polygon area proportions with `chisq.test()`.

But of course sampling can be adjusted. `st_sample()` is bit different from `sample()`, instead of vector of probabilities it accepts a vector of sizes, so you just multiply polygon area proportions with the total sample size.

You might want to address that `GCS_unknown` CRS too.

###### Setup and preparation of example data

```r
library(sf)
#> Linking to GEOS 3.9.3, GDAL 3.5.2, PROJ 8.2.1; sf_use_s2() is TRUE
library(dplyr, warn.conflicts = FALSE)

# prepare example data, us nc dataset from sf package as a base
example_sf <- read_sf(system.file("shape/nc.shp", package="sf")) %>% 
  mutate(c_lon = st_coordinates(st_centroid(geometry))[,1]) %>% 
  slice_max(c_lon, n = 12) %>% 
  select(geometry) %>% 
  mutate(ID = row_number() %>% as.factor(),
         area_sqkm = st_area(geometry) %>% units::set_units(km^2) %>% as.numeric(),
         .before = 1)

example_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 12 features and 2 fields
#> Geometry type: MULTIPOLYGON
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -77.16426 ymin: 34.58783 xmax: -75.45698 ymax: 36.55716
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> # A tibble: 12 × 3
#>    ID    area_sqkm                                                      geometry
#>  * <fct>     <dbl>                                            <MULTIPOLYGON [°]>
#>  1 1          944. (((-75.78317 36.22519, -75.77316 36.22926, -75.54497 35.7883…
#>  2 2          694. (((-76.00897 36.3196, -76.01735 36.33773, -76.03288 36.33598…
#>  3 3          988. (((-76.1673 35.69684, -76.21024 35.60439, -76.2328 35.59467,…
#>  4 4          616. (((-76.00897 36.3196, -75.95718 36.19377, -75.98134 36.16973…
#>  5 5         1678. (((-76.51894 35.57764, -76.5396 35.59404, -76.58588 35.60946…
#>  6 6          524. (((-76.29893 36.21423, -76.32423 36.23362, -76.37242 36.2523…
#>  7 7          626. (((-76.48053 36.07979, -76.53696 36.08792, -76.5756 36.10266…
#>  8 8         1006. (((-76.40843 35.69912, -76.63382 35.703, -76.83831 35.70546,…
#>  9 9          440. (((-76.68874 36.29452, -76.64822 36.31532, -76.60424 36.3149…
#> 10 10        1264. (((-77.14896 34.76433, -77.16426 34.77452, -77.15982 34.7885…
#> 11 11         903. (((-76.56251 36.34057, -76.60424 36.31498, -76.64822 36.3153…
#> 12 12         834. (((-76.94324 35.07003, -76.94423 35.09972, -76.98989 35.1540…
```

###### Sample and join polygons to include polygon ID

```r
# st_sample accepts a size vector, we can calculate it from area_sqkm ratios;
# st_sample() returns only a geometry list, to add matching polygon IDs, we'll
# pass it though st_sf() %>% st_join(example_sf[,"ID"]) 
set.seed(123)
s_points_sf <- example_sf %>% 
  mutate(sample_size = (area_sqkm / sum(area_sqkm) * 10000) %>% ceiling()) %>% 
  st_sample(size =  .[["sample_size"]]) %>% 
  st_sf() %>% 
  st_join(example_sf[,"ID"])

s_points_sf
#> Simple feature collection with 10007 features and 1 field
#> Geometry type: POINT
#> Dimension:     XY
#> Bounding box:  xmin: -77.16095 ymin: 34.58965 xmax: -75.46192 ymax: 36.55612
#> Geodetic CRS:  NAD27
#> First 10 features:
#>    ID                   geometry
#> 1   1 POINT (-75.76357 35.85772)
#> 2   1 POINT (-75.88236 35.78706)
#> 3   1 POINT (-75.47784 35.65193)
#> 4   1 POINT (-75.84168 35.66341)
#> 5   1  POINT (-75.8131 35.71313)
#> 6   1 POINT (-75.94289 35.68419)
#> 7   1 POINT (-75.86639 35.65802)
#> 8   1 POINT (-75.89701 35.80294)
#> 9   1 POINT (-75.78556 35.81975)
#> 10  1 POINT (-75.92244 35.81634)
```

###### Compare proportions of shape areas and point ID counts

```r
left_join(
  st_drop_geometry(example_sf),
  count(st_drop_geometry(s_points_sf), ID, name = "point_count")
) %>% 
  mutate(area_prop  = as.numeric(area_sqkm / sum(area_sqkm)),
         point_prop = point_count / sum(point_count))
#> Joining with `by = join_by(ID)`
#> # A tibble: 12 × 5
#>    ID    area_sqkm point_count area_prop point_prop
#>    <fct>     <dbl>       <int>     <dbl>      <dbl>
#>  1 1          944.         898    0.0897     0.0897
#>  2 2          694.         661    0.0660     0.0661
#>  3 3          988.         940    0.0940     0.0939
#>  4 4          616.         586    0.0586     0.0586
#>  5 5         1678.        1596    0.160      0.159 
#>  6 6          524.         499    0.0499     0.0499
#>  7 7          626.         596    0.0595     0.0596
#>  8 8         1006.         957    0.0956     0.0956
#>  9 9          440.         419    0.0418     0.0419
#> 10 10        1264.        1203    0.120      0.120 
#> 11 11         903.         859    0.0859     0.0858
#> 12 12         834.         793    0.0793     0.0792
```

<sup>Created on 2023-07-30 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Comment: Thanks a lot margusl for taking time to prepare this for me. I will try out using my dataset.